# Load image from worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

I've got an Excel Userform set up for rolling a 6-sided dice and reporting the results.  When the user pushes the command button I generate a random number 1-6, and then I'd like to have an image of the appropriate dice roll show up on the userform.  I have the dice images/shapes (e.g. dice_1, dice_2, etc) placed in a worksheet called "Inventory". I get "Run-time Error 13: Type mismatch" when I try to execute the following code, and the error occurs at the LoadPicture command. I realize that I don't have the If structure needed to select the pic corresponding to the dice roll, but that's simple enough to add once I figure out the syntax for loading the image.   Suggestions?

```
 Private Sub btnRollDice_Click()
 Dim DiceNum As Integer

     Randomize
     DiceNum = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)     
     pic1stDie.Picture = LoadPicture(Worksheets("Inventory").Shapes("dice_1"))
 End Sub
```

Comment: The easiest solution it to load the images into 6 hidden images controls on the Userform.   You can then change the image by using `pic1stDie.Picture = picdice_1.Picture`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out how to replicate Excel's functionality programmatically is to Record a Macro while doing the task manually, and then stop recording and check out the VBA that was generated for you, adjusting as necessary.

1. Record a Macro:

   - Developer > Record Macro > OK
2. Do the task manually:

   - Insert > Picture > select your picture
     (or however you're displaying these images)
3. Stop recording:

   - Developer > Stop
4. Check out the VBA that as generated for you:

   - Developer > Macros > select your macro > Edit
5. ...adjusting as necessary:

   - MSDN : [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code)
   - MSDN : [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros)

Following these steps generated this code for me:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\{myPath}\{myFile}.jpg").Select
```

To maximize the learning benefit of this task, take a moment to Google each of the commands it's using.  I'd add "excel msdn" to the end of my search query, thereby limiting the results to the official documentation from Microsoft Developer's Network.

A little trial-and-error goes a long way too (after backing up, of course), which is how I first figured out that many of the `Select` and `Activate`-related methods that the Macro Recorder adds can be safely removed.

With the example above, completed code might look like:

```
Sub btnRollDice_Click()
    Dim DiceNum As Integer
    Randomize
    DiceNum = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("C:\{myPath}\myDice" & DiceNum & ".jpg")
End Sub
```

If it's just a matter of displaying the same set of images, you could also have all the images (shapes) in the correct spot (even in the "same spot", on top of each other) and set the shape's `Visible` property to True/False as needed, such as:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("My Die 4").Visible = False 'hides this image
```

Comment: Your answer is well laid out, but isn't the OP's point not to insert a picture, since the images are already contained in the worksheet "Inventory"?